# Can Server IP Address Be Seen On Receiving End Of cURL Request? (Cloudflare)

Tags: http, cloudflare

When using Cloudflare, I understand all requests made too my server will not see my servers IP address.

Is this the same for all requests made from my server to any API's or URL's?

For example, say I am using cURL within PHP, I then made requests to Facebook's Graph API... Since my server is using Cloudflare, **would FB see the request came from Cloudflare's IP address?**

**It would not see my server IP?** or any domain name on my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When using Cloudflare, I understand all requests made too my server
> will not see my servers IP address.

If the proxy (Orange cloud) is turned on for your website, then yes. If it is *DNS-only*, it will be sent directly to your server and your IP will be exposed.

> Is this the same for all requests made from my server to any API's or URL's?
>
> For example, say I am using cURL within PHP, I then made requests to
> Facebook's Graph API... Since my server is using Cloudflare, would FB
> see the request came from Cloudflare's IP address?
>
> It would not see my server IP? or any domain name on my server?

No, [Cloudflare is a reverse proxy](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/cdn/glossary/reverse-proxy/), not a forward proxy (commonly known as HTTP proxy, or just *proxy*). When you do an API or cURL request, the host would see your server's public IP. If you wish to hide your server's IP, you could use a forward proxy service such as [Smartproxy](https://smartproxy.com/proxies/residential-proxies) (good services are paid), or [setup your own proxy using NGINX](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/how-to-use-nginx-as-an-https-forward-proxy-server_595799).